# How to encode in 10 different class the last two words from multiple .csv files in a folder?

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, encoding

I have a folder with 468 .csv files (Folder_file1_MR, Folder_file2_MR, ...., Folder_file6_MW), and the name of each .csv file ends with two letters corresponding to a specific class. In total, there are 10 different classes in the dataset, and I am trying to associate each class with a number ranging from 1 to 10. I tried this code, but I get all the classes associated with label 0. How can I solve this?

```
list_files = os.listdir(FOLDNAME)
#labels = np.genfromtxt("target" + FOLDNAME + ".txt", delimiter=",")

for i, j in range(list_files):
    dataset = pd.read_csv(list_files)


features_all = []
target_all = []
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()


for i, f in enumerate(list_files):
    data = np.genfromtxt(os.path.join(FOLDNAME, f), delimiter=",")
    
    target_all.append(f[-5:7]) #metto le 
    features_all.append(extract_features(data))
features_all = np.asarray(features_all)

target_all = le.fit_transform(target_all)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "and I am trying to associate each class with a number ranging from 1 to 10. I tried this code, but I get all the classes associated with label 0." In your own words, what do these labels mean? Why should any of the classes be associated with any different number? What is the rule that tells you, which number to associate with the class?

Answer (score 0):

There are some errors in your code (e.g. `for i, j in range(list_files):` will raise a TypeError as you can't unpack 2 variables from range), and it's difficult to follow.

That said, your problem has an easy solution. You can create a `set` of the last 2 letters of each file name, then use a dictionary comprehension to assign a number to them.

The below code fits your brief.

```
import pandas as pd
list_files=['file_1_YF.txt', 'file_2_SE.txt', … ] #add file names to test
df=pd.DataFrame({'Files':list_files}) #create dataframe with your list of files
classes=set([f[-6:-4] for f in list_files]) #creates set of each 2-letter sequence before .csv in file names
classes_dict={c:n+1 for n,c in enumerate(classes)} #arbitrarily assigns a class value to each. Used n+1 as asked for range 1..10.
df['Class']=df['Files'].map(lambda x: classes_dict[x[-6:-4]]) #use map with lambda function that looks up 2-letter sequence of filename in dict
```